# Sum columns between dataframes in list accordingly to respective rows

Tags: r, list, dataframe, sum, col

I have got the following list:

```
df = read.table(text = 'Var1 Freq
1 12
2 19
3 3
5 7
6 55
9 17', header = TRUE)

df1 = read.table(text = 'Var1 Freq
1 16
2 1
3 22
5 87
6 5
7 9
11 76', header = TRUE)

df2 = read.table(text = 'Var1 Freq
1 17
2 11
5 7
6 32
7 10
15 6
20 54', header = TRUE)

lst = list(df, df1, df2)
```

I need to sum each `Freq` col with the relative `Var1` row for each data.frame.

Here my desired output:

```
Var1 Freq
1 45
2 31
3 25
5 101
6 92
7 19
9 17
11 76
15 6
20 54
```

How can I do this? Does `Map` help in this case?

Thanks

Comment: I ran a microbenchmark on the 3 answers below: do.call, dplyr and data.table. DT was fastest, dplyr took 1.6 times as long and do.call took 6.3 times as long, for those interested. I used the dplyr answer because it's easier to apply to multiple columns. At least it was for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `do.call` to `rbind` the individual dataframes of the list into a single data.frame and then use `aggregate` to `sum`

```
with(do.call(rbind, lst), aggregate(Freq, by = list(Var1), sum))
#   Group.1   x
#1        1  45
#2        2  31
#3        3  25
#4        5 101
#5        6  92
#6        7  19
#7        9  17
#8       11  76
#9       15   6
#10      20  54
```

Comment: You could add the column names with `aggregate(cbind(Freq=Freq), by = list(Var1=Var1), sum))`.

Answer (score 4):

Another idea:

```
library(dplyr) 
bind_rows(lst) %>% group_by(Var1) %>% summarise(Freq = sum(Freq))
```

Which gives:

```
## A tibble: 10 × 2
#    Var1  Freq
#   <int> <int>
#1      1    45
#2      2    31
#3      3    25
#4      5   101
#5      6    92
#6      7    19
#7      9    17
#8     11    76
#9     15     6
#10    20    54
```

Answer (score 2):

Another idea is `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lst)[, .(Freq = sum(Freq)), Var1]
#    Var1 Freq
# 1:    1   45
# 2:    2   31
# 3:    3   25
# 4:    5  101
# 5:    6   92
# 6:    9   17
# 7:    7   19
# 8:   11   76
# 9:   15    6
#10:   20   54
```